# How to write Barycentric weights in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

The question is to implement barycentric weights in numerical analysis:
[image]

and here is my code:

```
def barycentric_weights(j,n):
weight=1
for k in range(0,n+1):
    if k != j:
        weight=weight*(1/(xj-xk))
    else:
        weight=weight*1
```

what I'm stuck is that I don't know how to correctly call xj and xk. Should I call them as tuples?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Primary question here is what is your input, how do you store your values. And please fix the indentation - it is part of the code.

Comment: Usually you use a list or an (numpy) array for `x`.